# Rails render static pages based on Domain name

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a specific case scenario as follows.

I have a single ROR application which will run under multiple domains using the same deployment. So I will have to serve a few static assets, (images, html files) as per the domain name. Can any please suggest what would be the ideal way to do this?

In my application controller, I could find out the domain name

```
def current_domain
    @current_domain ||= Domain.find_by_domain(request.host.gsub(/^www\./, ''))
end
```

But can i use this helper inside my controller to serve static files in the public directory?  Also the creation of these domain names and static pages for that domain is handled by a central admin and can be dynamically done at any point of time. I may have to make different directories as per the domain name and store the static assets within them. But then how do I render this as and when a request to the particular domain comes in is the question I have in hand.

Any help on the how to approach this problem with Rails would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest an application layout for each domain, and using dynamic layouts to pick the correct one in your controllers.

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  layout :products_layout

  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
    def products_layout
      @current_domain.special? ? "special" : "products"
    end

end
```